# How do I specify an element in XSD is a link as per the Atom definition?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, atom-feed

An xml document may contain

```
 <links xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xml:base="http://some-website.org">
    <atom:link rel="self" href="/resource/1"/>
</links>
```

How can I assert the existence of this element in the corresponding XSD? I have

```
 <xs:element name="links" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"/>
```

but this seems too permissive, as a document containing an arbitrary `<links/>` element will be considered valid.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<xs:element name="links" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="atom:link"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

define the `links` element so that it must contain exactly one `atom:link` sub-element (provided you import the Atom schema).